# IIS dynamic URL rewrite

Tags: iis, iis-10

I'm trying in Microsoft IIS 10 to do dynamic URL rewrite / redirect based on a condition that the URL contains specific info.

Match URL / Pattern: **mysite/pages/viewpage.action?uniqueurl**

Rewrite URL: **mysite.xyz.xyz/pages/viewpage.action?**uniqueurl****

What I want to achieve is that whatever you write after **mysite/pages/viewpage.action?** it needs to rewrite to the same URL just with **mysite.xyz.xyz** added instead of only **mysite**.

Example 1:
**mysite/pages/viewpage.action?thisisexample1** -> **mysite.xyz.xyz/pages/viewpage.action?thisisexample1**

Example 2: **mysite/pages/viewpage.action?anothersite** -> **mysite.xyz.xyz/pages/viewpage.action?anothersite**

When I'm trying to set up the above in the URL rewrite section i just end up at: **https://mysite.xyz.xyz/pages/viewpage.action**.

I have a generel HTTP redirect aswell to **https://mysite.xyz.xyz** when you come from **mysite** which works fine but I need to try and get specific URL rewrites to work aswell.

Comment: You forgot to append query strings in your rewrite rule(s). Well, if HTTP Redirect works for you, then you don't need to master URL Rewrite right now. But someday you might find the need.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It was to add HTTP redirect parameters to the HTTP redirect and change the Redirect Behaviour.

I added $S$Q to the HTTP redirect which fixed the issue in the regards to the question mark in the redirect which IIS couldn't handle without the extra parameters.

[image: HTTP redirect parameters]

Besides that I need to change the Redirect Behaviour so I put a checkmark in 'Redirect all requests to exact destination (instead of relative to destination)

[image: Redirect Behaviour]

Edit: Typo